# XPath Query won't work without "text()" ending

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

So i'm trying to learn some xml parsing here, and I'm getting the hang of it, but for whatever reason, I seem to have to tack on "text()" at the end of each query, otherwise I get null values returned to me. I don't actually understand the function of this "text()" ending but I know it's not necessary and I'm wondering why I can't omit it. Please help! Here is my code:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ParseClass 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
IOException, XPathExpressionException 
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("C:\\Users\\Brandon\\Job\\XPath\\XPath_Sample_Stuff\\catalog.xml");
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/catalog/book[author='Thurman, Paula']/title/text()");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
  }
}
```

PS. In case you didn't notice. i'm using XPath and DOM for my parsing.

Comment: But If I'm still getting an element, why does it return null without the text()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `getNodeValue` on your result, and as [this docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) show (see the table) it is `null` for a node of type `Element`. When you use `text()`, the returned set now contains nodes of type `Text`, so you get the results you wanted (i.e. the contents of the title element instead of the element itself).

I'd also suggest seeing [this](http://www.xquery.com/tips_and_tricks/using_text_in_XPath.html) for more info on the usage of `text()` in xpath.

And if you want to extract the text from your element, directly, you could use [`getTextContent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) instead of `getNodeValue`:

```
// Will work for both element and text nodes
System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, i'm just getting into parsing so i'm still learning. I really do love stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your Xpath expression is invalid (I am considering it as typo). Attributes are indicated with `@` so correct xpath will be `/catalog/book[@author='Thurman, Paula']/title/text()`.

`/catalog/book[@author='Thurman, Paula']/title/` will match the `<title>` node from your xml whereas `/catalog/book[@author='Thurman, Paula']/title/text()` with match the text node of `<title>` i.e if title node was something like `<title>The Godfather</title>`the later expression would match `The Godfather`.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: don't use DOM. There are many tree representations of XML available in the Java world (JDOM, XOM, DOM4J) that are vastly more usable than DOM. DOM is full of gotcha's like the one you just encountered, where getNodeValue() on an element returns null. The only reason anyone uses DOM is that (a) it came originally from W3C, and (b) it found its way into the JDK. But that all happened an awfully long time ago, and people have learnt from its design mistakes.